# Solving IVP with Laplace transform involving step function and summation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, solution-verification, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

Given the IVP
$$ y'' + y = f(t) , \qquad\quad y(0) = 0 , \quad y'(0) = 0 , \tag{1}$$
where 
$$ f_{k} (t) = u_{0} + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} u_{k \pi}(t). \tag{2}$$
We want to find the solution.

My attempt is as follows :
$$  f(t) = u_{0}(t) -2u_{\pi}(t) + 2u_{2\pi}(t) -2u_{3\pi}(t) + \dots $$
Therefore, we can compute the Laplace transform on both sides of Equation 1
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[y'' +y] &= \mathcal{L}[u_{0}(t) -2u_{\pi}(t) + 2u_{2\pi}(t) -2u_{3\pi}(t) + \dots ]\\
\mathcal{L}[y''] + \mathcal{L}[y] &=\mathcal{L}[u_{0}(t)] - 2\mathcal{L}[u_{\pi}(t)] + 2\mathcal{L}[u_{2\pi}(t)] -2 \mathcal{L}[u_{3\pi}(t)] + \dots\\
Y(s)(s^{2} + 1) &= \frac{1}{s}-2\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s}+2\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{s}-2\frac{e^{-3\pi s}}{s}+\dots\\
\therefore Y(s) &= \frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1)} - 2\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s(s^{2}+1)}+2\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{s(s^{2}+1)} -2\frac{e^{-3\pi s}}{s(s^{2}+1)} + \dots \\
\implies y(t) &= \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[\frac{1}{s(s^{2}+1)} \right] - 2\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s(s^{2}+1)} \right] +2 \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[\frac{e^{-2\pi s}}{s(s^{2}+1)} \right] + \dots\\
& \because \frac{1}{s(s^2 +1)} = \left(\frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2 +1} \right), \\
&= 1-\cos(t) - 2 u_{\pi }(t) \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2 +1} \right]+2 u_{2\pi }(t) \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s} - \frac{s}{s^2 +1}\right] + \dots \\
&= 1-\cos(t) - 2 u_{\pi }(t) (1-\cos(t-\pi)) + 2 u_{2\pi }(t)(1-\cos(t-2\pi)) + \dots \\
\therefore y(t) &= 1-\cos(t) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} u_{k\pi}(t)(1-\cos(t-k\pi)) .
\end{align}

I'm not quite certain about my reasoning. Particularly, I'm unsure if the given form of the solution ,which involves a summation ,is adequate. Can anyone tell me if I went wrong anywhere ?

Comment: Looks good to me...I see no mistakes in your reasoning Hitech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. Good job. You can avoid lots of calculation by keeping the sigma notation:
$$Y(s)(s^{2} + 1) =   \dfrac {1}{s } + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} \dfrac {e^{-k\pi s}}{s }$$
$$Y(s)=  \dfrac {1}{s(s^{2} + 1) } + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k} \dfrac {e^{-k\pi s}}{s(s^{2} + 1) }$$
$$Y(s)=  \left (\dfrac 1 s -\dfrac s{s^{2} + 1 } \right) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k}{e^{-k\pi s}} \left (\dfrac 1 s -\dfrac s{s^{2} + 1 } \right)$$
$$y(t)=  1-\cos t + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k}{u_{k\pi} }{(1-\cos(t-k\pi ))}$$